# Trying to do an 'if' statement in pandas dataframe but getting "KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pd dataframe:

```
aggressor_side     auction_trade  ...       trade_type        market_state
0               0          False  ...            LIT       DARK_TRADE
1               0          False  ...           DARK       CONTINUOUS_TRADING
2               0          False  ...            LIT       CONTINUOUS_TRADING
```

I would like to map the `trade_type` of a row to `GREEN` if that row's `market_state` is `DARK_TRADE`.

I tried:

```
trades.loc['DARK_TRADE' in trades['market_state'], 'trade_type'] = 'GREEN'
```

Expected output:

```
      aggressor_side     auction_trade  ...       trade_type        market_state
0               0          False        ...           GREEN       DARK_TRADE
1               0          False        ...           DARK       CONTINUOUS_TRADING
2               0          False        ...            LIT       CONTINUOUS_TRADING
```

Comment: Use `trades['trade_type'] = trades['trade_type'].mask(trades['market_state'].eq('DARK_TRADE'), 'GREEN')`